# ASP.net AJAX Control Toolkit will not recognise my specified css classes in the autocomlete extender?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I am trying to specify CSS classes for the [autocomplete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx) control:

```
CompletionListCssClass="completionListElement"
CompletionListItemCssClass="listItem"
CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="highlightedListItem"
```

When I try this, it returns this error:

> Parser Error Message: Type 'AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender' does not have a public property named 'CompletionListCssClass'.

Those properties come right from the ACT website.  Why won't it recognize them?

Comment: I've tried upgrading the toolkit, but it breaks a lot of things on the site.  I will have to find another way.  I've never had so much problems applying a css class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this problem recently. It sounds like you might not be using the most recent version of the ToolKit. Try upgrading to the most recent version - I bet that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

are you sure you have the most recent version of the ajax control toolkit?

Comment: I am having this problem with AjaxControlToolKit v18.1.1 installed. Can you provide any additional suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are using old `AJAXControlToolkit` which doesn't have CSS feature

Get the latest Toolkit from [codeplex Ajax articles](http://csharpdotnetfreak.blogspot.com/search/label/AJAX?max-results=5)